# CPU Usage Suddenly Decreased on Two Servers

Tags: cpu, performance, windows-server-2008, cpu-usage, sql-server

We are running 6 2008 SQL Servers on Windows Server 2008 R2, 4 of which were sitting around 50%+ CPU usage during peak usage. On Wednesday, the CPU on 2 of these 4 servers dropped by 20% and performance greatly increased on our production service.

I can't see any immediate reason for this decrease in CPU usage, but the Event Viewer shows a "Kernel-General" event at the exact time the CPU usage decreased on both servers. The message was: "The system time has changed to ‎2017‎-‎11‎-‎29T14:56:49.967000000Z from ‎2017‎-‎11‎-‎29T14:56:36.200429700Z."

Could this have had any impact on CPU usage, or is this entirely coincidental? If so, why would this have any impact?

Comment: Probably coincidental, only thing I can think of possibly it cancelled whatever actions which were being performed at the time. Did the % go back up to 50% or stay at 20%?

Comment: @Crazyd It's stayed at around 20-35% consistently (previously 40%+ consistently for weeks) since last Wednesday